# Programmatically create azure Service Bus queue and Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on a scenario where when I need to create a new servicebus queue and an azure function that is triggered whenever a message is dropped in the said queue. Is there a way to call an API pass in some parameters and have the queue and function created ?

Any inputs will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Technically, You can achieve both as far as i know.

You can create a new function with the [`CLI command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?tabs=bash%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-csharp) , i do not think there is an API to do the same.

To create a Service Bus queue you can do it with the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus/) package and here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650497/creating-an-azure-servicebus-queue-via-code) already.